# HuggingFace-Transformers --- NER single sentence/sample prediction

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to predict with the NER model, as in the tutorial from huggingface (it contains only the training+evaluation part).

I am following this exact tutorial here : https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/examples/token_classification.ipynb

The training works flawlessly, but the problems that I have begin when I try to predict on a simple sample.

```
model_checkpoint = "distilbert-base-uncased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)
loaded_model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('./my_model_own_custom_training.pth',
                                         from_tf=False)



input_sentence = "John Nash is a great mathematician, he lives in France"
tokenized_input_sentence = tokenizer([input_sentence],
                                     truncation=True, 
                                     is_split_into_words=False,
                                     return_tensors='pt')
predictions = loaded_model(tokenized_input_sentence["input_ids"])[0]
```

Predictions is of shape `(1,13,768)`

How can I arrive at the final result of the form `[JOHN <-> ‘B-PER’, … France <-> “B-LOC”]`, where `B-PER` and `B-LOC` are two ground truth labels, representing the tag for a person and location respectively?

The result of the prediction is:

```
torch.Size([1, 13, 768])
```

If I write:

```
print(predictions.argmax(axis=2))
tensor([613, 705, 244, 620, 206, 206, 206, 620, 620, 620, 477, 693, 308])
```

I get the tensor above.

However I would have expected to get the tensor representing the ground truth `[0…8]` labels from the ground truth annotations.

Summary when loading the model :

> ```
> loading configuration file ./my_model_own_custom_training.pth/config.json
> Model config DistilBertConfig {
> “name_or_path": “distilbert-base-uncased”,
> “activation”: “gelu”,
> “architectures”: [
> “DistilBertForTokenClassification”
> ],
> “attention_dropout”: 0.1,
> “dim”: 768,
> “dropout”: 0.1,
> “hidden_dim”: 3072,
> “id2label”: {
> “0”: “LABEL_0”,
> “1”: “LABEL_1”,
> “2”: “LABEL_2”,
> “3”: “LABEL_3”,
> “4”: “LABEL_4”,
> “5”: “LABEL_5”,
> “6”: “LABEL_6”,
> “7”: “LABEL_7”,
> “8”: “LABEL_8”
> },
> “initializer_range”: 0.02,
> “label2id”: {
> “LABEL_0”: 0,
> “LABEL_1”: 1,
> “LABEL_2”: 2,
> “LABEL_3”: 3,
> “LABEL_4”: 4,
> “LABEL_5”: 5,
> “LABEL_6”: 6,
> “LABEL_7”: 7,
> “LABEL_8”: 8
> },
> “max_position_embeddings”: 512,
> “model_type”: “distilbert”,
> “n_heads”: 12,
> “n_layers”: 6,
> “pad_token_id”: 0,
> “qa_dropout”: 0.1,
> “seq_classif_dropout”: 0.2,
> “sinusoidal_pos_embds”: false,
> "tie_weights”: true,
> “transformers_version”: “4.8.1”,
> “vocab_size”: 30522
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a bit trickier than expected[Huge credits to Niels Rogge].

Firstly, loading models in `huggingface-transformers` can be done in (at least) two ways:

1. `AutoModel.from_pretrained('./my_model_own_custom_training.pth', from_tf=False)`
2. `AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained('./my_model_own_custom_training.pth', from_tf=False)`

It seems that, according to the task at hand, different `AutoModels` subclasses need to be used. In this scenario I posted, it is the `AutoModelForTokenClassification()` that has to be used.

After that, a solution to obtain the predictions would be to do the following:

```
# forward pass
outputs = model(**encoding)
logits = outputs.logits

predictions = logits.argmax(-1)
```